# ajax success method fallback type does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

action page return type is x in php but success else happens

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "user.php?mysts=chck",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#cntstngfrm").serialize(),
        success: function (cevap) {
            console.log("myrequest =  "+cevap);
            if (cevap == "x") {
                alert("dasdasd");
            }else{
               alert("999");
            }
        }
 });
```

user.php :

```
if (isset($_GET['mysts'])=="chck"){
     $duzenle=$db->prepare("UPDATE mmb SET
        mmbss=:mmbss

        WHERE id={$_POST['wqrid']}");

    $control=$duzenle->execute(array(
        'mmbss'=>$_POST['mmbss']
    ));
    if ($control) {
        echo "x";
    }else{
        echo "y";
    }
}
```

console :
[image]

everything ok but it gives alert 999. Thansk for help.

Comment: Just to check what is being sent back, try `console.log("myrequest="+cevap+"!");` the extra character can show if there is any whitespace around the x.

Comment: gave a printout like this, no space: https://hizliresim.com/ClNOKL

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your second images, there is a newline `\n` character, use `.trim()` to remove it

```
success: function (cevap) {
  console.log("myrequest =  " + cevap);
  cevap = cevap.trim(); // <= remove space or newline
  if (cevap == "x") {
    alert("dasdasd");
  }
  else {
    alert("999");
  }
}
```

or check again `user.php` and make sure there are no another `echo`

Comment: Thank you so much trim function solved my problem